# Why am I getting AttributeError dict_keys object has no value append?

Tags: python, loops, parsing, attributeerror

From this code, why am I getting a dict_keys attribute error when I have assigned the variable as a list above the loops (release_list.append), I believe it may be an indentation error because it was working before I tried to put it in it's own def but I can't get it working.

```
import requests
import html
import json
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    
def removeDupes(seq):
    # Not order preserving
    keys = {}
    for e in seq:
        keys[e] = 1
    return keys.keys()



def Add_VideoID_ToDB(url):

#url = sys.argv[1:]
    print(url)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.text)
        searchStartText = "class=\"last-page\">"
        searchStart = response.text.find(searchStartText) + len(searchStartText)
        searchEndText = "</a>"
        searchEnd = response.text.find(searchEndText, searchStart)
        lastPage = response.text[searchStart:searchEnd]
        print(lastPage)

        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        trimmed_html = parsed_html.body.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'thumb-block'})
        
        for div in trimmed_html:
            links = div.findAll('a')
            ids = div.findAll('id')
        for idfound in ids:
            print(idfound['data-id'])
    
#print(links[0]) section html
        release_list = []
        release_dictionary = {}
        sorted_list = []
    for a in links:

        if (a['href'][:6]) == "/video":
            print("link : " + a['href'])
            release_list.append(a['href'])
            release_list = removeDupes(release_list)
            sorted_list = list(release_list)
```

I have tried moving the code around into different indentation blocks but nothing is working

Comment: Change `return keys.keys()` to `return list(keys.keys())`. The `keys()` method doesn't return a list of keys, it returns a view object that iterates over the keys.

Comment: You can also simplify it to just `return list(keys)`

Comment: Actually, the best way to remove duplicates is `return list(set(seq))`

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but now my list only returns one value and it should be about 26 links

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code snippet so we can be clear on what is inside the loops

Comment: That's where i'm confused, i've tried changing them and can't work out the correct indentations

Comment: You don't need to call `removeDupes()` in the loop. Do it after the loop is done. And `sorted_list` is not sorted, it's just a copy of `release_list` in the same order. Maybe you mean `sorted_list = sorted(release_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `key.keys()`

updated section : removeDupes()

```
def removeDupes(seq):
    return list(set(seq))
```

Also the indentation is wrong for the for loop looping over link

```
for div in trimmed_html:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    # your code
    for a in links:
        # your code
```

EDIT:

As per optimized way by Barmer in comments

Comment: This is the hard way to do it. Just do `return list(set(seq))`

Comment: Excellent, the error was indeed wrong for the a in links bit, I confused myself. It returns them all successfully now, I will also change the easier way to return the list without dupes. Thank you both for your time and input